# React : TypeError: _this4 is undefined react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello everyone I am building an app using Reactjs and am stuck. The issue is that i have a function **getDocFinancialInfo(fileId)** which is binded to an onClick event for an element **label**. Every time i click on the label i get the **TypeError: _this4 is undefined react**. The code is provided below

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import './UploadDocument.css'
    import spinner from './spinner.gif'
    import verified from './verified.png';
    import notverified from './not-verified.png';
    import Requirements from './Requirement.js'


    class UploadDocument extends Component{

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          application: [],
          document:[],
          id: null,
          files: [],
          docFinancialInfo: [],
          uploaded: null
        }
      }


      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ id: sessionStorage.getItem('currentId') });

        this.getApplicationInfo()
          .then(application => this.setState({ application: application.application }))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));


        this.displayDocumentInfo();

        this.displayDocumentsFinancialInfo();
      }

      reload = () =>   {
          //RELOAD COMPONENT
          this.componentDidMount();
      };

      displayDocumentsFinancialInfo = async() => {

        await this.getDocumentsFinancialInfo(sessionStorage.getItem('currentId'))
          .then(docFinancialInfo => this.setState({ docFinancialInfo: docFinancialInfo.docFinancialInfo }))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));

          //console.log("Doc Finance >> "+this.state.docFinancialInfo);
      }

      getDocumentsFinancialInfo = async(appId) => {

        const response = await fetch('/getDocumentsFinancialInfo/'+appId);
        const body = await response.json();

        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

        return body;
      }

      displayDocumentInfo = async() => {

        await this.getDocumentInfo(sessionStorage.getItem('currentId'))
          .then(files => this.setState({ files: files.files }))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));

          //console.log("Files >> "+this.state.files);
      }

      getDocumentInfo = async(appId) => {

        const response = await fetch('/getDocumentInfo/'+appId);
        const body = await response.json();

        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

        return body;
      }





      getApplicationInfo = async () => {
          const appId = sessionStorage.getItem('currentId');
          const response = await fetch('/getApplicationInfo/'+appId);
          const body = await response.json();

          if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

          return body;
        };

      back(){
        this.props.history.push("/");
      }

      submit = async() => {


        var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');

        if(fileInput.files.length === 0){
            alert("Select at least one file to upload.");
        }else{
            this.spinner("show");

            for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
                await this.uploadDocument(fileInput.files[i].name)
              .then(document => {
                this.setState({ document: document.document });
                //console.log("DOCUMENT>>>>"+JSON.stringify(this.state.document));

                if(this.state.document.hasOwnProperty('DocId')){
                  this.displayDocumentInfo();

                  this.reload();
                  this.setState({ uploaded: !this.state.uploaded });
                }else if(this.state.document.hasOwnProperty('code')){
                  if(this.state.document["errno"] === "ETIMEDOUT"){
                    alert("ERROR: Could not connect to server. File '"+fileInput.files[i].name+"' could not be uploaded.");
                  }else if(this.state.document["errno"] === 1265){
                    var sqlMessage = this.state.document["sqlMessage"];
                    var column = sqlMessage.substring(sqlMessage.indexOf("'")+1, sqlMessage.lastIndexOf("'"));
                    alert("ERROR: File '"+fileInput.files[i].name+"' has error in value for field '"+column+"'.")
                  }else if(this.state.document["errno"] === 1048){
                    alert("ERROR: "+this.state.document["sqlMessage"]+" in the File '"+fileInput.files[i].name+"'");
                  }else if(this.state.document["errno"] === 503){
                    alert(this.state.document["sqlMessage"]);
                  }
                }
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log("ERROR>>>>"+err);
              });
              // console.log("NI Nmber>>>"+this.state.document["NI Number"]);
            }
            this.spinner("hide");
        }
      }

      spinner(display){
        if(display === 'show'){
          document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById("container").style.WebkitFilter = 'blur(1px)';
          document.getElementById("spinner").style.zIndex = '2';
          document.getElementById("pano").style.zIndex = '3';
          document.getElementById("pano").style.position = 'fixed';
          document.getElementById("pano").style.width = '100%';
          document.getElementById("pano").style.height = '100%';
        }else if(display === 'hide'){
          document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById("container").style.WebkitFilter = 'none';
          document.getElementById("spinner").style.zIndex = '0';
          document.getElementById("pano").style.zIndex = '0';
          document.getElementById("pano").style.position = 'none';
          document.getElementById("pano").style.width = '10%';
          document.getElementById("pano").style.height = '10%';
        }
      }

      uploadDocument = async (file) => {
        const appId = sessionStorage.getItem('currentId');
        const response = await fetch('/uploadDocument/'+appId+'/'+file);
        const body = await response.json();

        //console.log("body>>"+body.document);

        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

        return body;
      }

      closeRequirements(){
        var req = document.getElementById('requirements');
        req.style.display = "none";
      }

      getDocFinancialInfo(fileId){
          sessionStorage.setItem('docId',fileId);

          var req = document.getElementById('requirements');
          req.style.display = "block";

      }

      render(){
        const filesToRender = this.state.files.filter(files => files);
        const filesLength = filesToRender.length;

        var finData = this.state.docFinancialInfo;
        var applicationInfo = this.state.application;

        var employeeNameApplication;
        var niNumberApplication;
        var basicPayApplication;
        var totalMonthlyPayApplication;
        var payFromCurrentEmployerApplication;


        for(var app in applicationInfo){

          employeeNameApplication = applicationInfo[app][1] + " " + applicationInfo[app][2];
          niNumberApplication = applicationInfo[app][4];
          basicPayApplication = applicationInfo[app][5];
          totalMonthlyPayApplication = applicationInfo[app][6];
          payFromCurrentEmployerApplication = applicationInfo[app][7];
        }

        var employeeNameDoc;
        var niNumberDoc;
        var basicPayDoc;
        var totalMonthlyPayDoc;
        var payFromCurrentEmployerDoc;
        var docId;

        var notVerifedStatus = 0;
        var docVerificationStatus = [];
        finData.forEach(function (docFinInfo, index){
          docId = docFinInfo[0];
          var docName = docFinInfo[9];
          var docType = docFinInfo[8];
          employeeNameDoc = docFinInfo[3];
          niNumberDoc = docFinInfo[4];
          if(docType === "P60"){
            console.log("Inside P60");
            payFromCurrentEmployerDoc = docFinInfo[7];

            if(employeeNameApplication !== employeeNameDoc){
              notVerifedStatus++;
            }

            if(niNumberApplication !== niNumberDoc){
              notVerifedStatus++;
            }

            if(payFromCurrentEmployerApplication > payFromCurrentEmployerDoc){
              notVerifedStatus++;
            }
          }else{
            console.log("Inside Payslip");
            basicPayDoc = docFinInfo[8];
            totalMonthlyPayDoc = docFinInfo[8];

            if(employeeNameApplication !== employeeNameDoc){
              notVerifedStatus++;
            }

            if(niNumberApplication !== niNumberDoc){
              notVerifedStatus++;
            }

            if(basicPayApplication !== basicPayDoc){
              notVerifedStatus++;
            }

            if(totalMonthlyPayApplication !== totalMonthlyPayDoc){
              notVerifedStatus++;
            }
          }

          if(notVerifedStatus > 0){
              docVerificationStatus[index] = <td className="red"><img src={notverified} alt="Not Verified"/><label onClick={()=>this.getDocFinancialInfo(docId)}>Not Verified{docId}</label></td>;
          }else{
              docVerificationStatus[index] = <td className="green"><img src={verified} alt="Verified" /><label>Verified</label></td>;
          }
        });



        var files;
        if(filesLength > 0){
          files = <div id="files_content">
                    <table className="file-uploaded">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Document Name</td>
                                <td>Document Type</td>
                                <td>Status</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {
                      this.state.docFinancialInfo.map((doc,index) => (
                        <tr>
                            <td><label>{doc[9]}</label></td>
                            <td>{doc[8]}</td>
                            {docVerificationStatus[index]}
                        </tr>

                      ))
                    }
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                   </div>;
        }else{
          files = <div id="files_content">
                    <p><label className="no-content">No Files have been uploaded.</label></p>
                  </div>;
        }


        return(
          <div>
                <div id="spinner">
                    <img className="spinner-img" src={spinner}  alt="Waiting"/>
                </div>
                <div id="pano"></div>
                <div id="container">
                  {
                    this.state.application.map(app => (
                        <div id="application-info">
                            <h3>Mortagage Application for {app[1]} {app[2]}</h3>
                        </div>
                      )
                    )
                  }

                <div className="files-heading">
                    <span onClick={()=>this.back()}>Cases</span>
                    <span className="heading">Tasks</span>
                    <span >Case Allocation</span>
                    <span >Other</span>
                </div>


                <div id="file-upload">
                    <div id="customer-information">
                    {
                      this.state.application.map(app => (
                          <div id="customer">
                              <p><label id="customer-name">{app[1]} {app[2]}</label></p>
                              <p><span>{app[8]}</span></p>
                          </div>
                        )
                      )
                    }
                    </div>

                    {
                      notVerifedStatus > 0 ? <div className="files-uploaded-heading">
                                                <span>Info</span>
                                                <span>Tasks</span>
                                                <span className="heading">Requirements <span className="dot"><label>{notVerifedStatus}</label></span></span>
                                             </div>
                                           : <div className="files-uploaded-heading">
                                                  <span>Info</span>
                                                  <span>Tasks</span>
                                                  <span className="heading">Requirements</span>
                                              </div>
                    }

                    <div id="file-container">
                        <div className="file-input">
                            <label>Please Upload 3 latest PaySlips & P60 : </label>
                            <input type="file" id="file-input" multiple/>
                            <p>
                              <button type="button" className="button" name="save" value="save" onClick={()=>this.submit()}>Save</button>
                              <button type="button" className="button" name="back" value="back" onClick={()=>this.back()}>Back</button>
                            </p>
                        </div>

                        <div id="files">
                          {files}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="requirements">
                      <div id="requirements-content">
                        <span className="close" onClick={()=>this.closeRequirements()}>&times;</span>
                        <Requirements />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default UploadDocument
```

I have provided the full component. I know the code is not as clean as it could be but I am still learning. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: `getDocFinancialInfo(fileId)` inside of `render` looks very odd. Could you include your entire component instead?

Comment: Is `getDocFinancialInfo` declared in `render` method? If so, move it outside. `this` reffers to your class

Comment: getDocFinancialInfo(fileId) is outside render. I have corrected it now.

Comment: What a mess I hope you're not formatting your code like that! Confusing as there is not refering to `this` inside getDocFinancialInfo, have you removed code?

Comment: Sorry if you are confused. I am still new to react. I donot get what you mean by not refereing to 'this' inside getDocFinancialInfo? Could you please explain.

Comment: @Tholle I have provided the full component.

Comment: Your code is pretty hard to understand for a few reasons: 
1. The formatting and indentation is not what it should be. Please indent your code properly.
2. There is a lot of code that isn't related to your specific problem. Could you please isolate the part that causes trouble?
3. There are many typing errors present, for example `docFinacialInfo`, `notVerifedStatus`, or `docVerficationStatus`. Could you correct those to improve the readability?

Comment: @ThijsKramer 1) I had earlier provided  only the problem areas but then decided to provide the entire component. 2) I have made correction to the typos. 3) if you just look at the **getDocFinancialInfo(fieldId)** and the element that calls this function **label**. Check the **foreach** function and you will see the element that is supposed to call the above mentioned function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the irrelevant part from your code, and I've reduced it to this situation:

```
finData.forEach(function (docFinInfo, index){
  // ...
  if(notVerifedStatus > 0){
      docVerificationStatus[index] = <td className="red"><img src={notverified} alt="Not Verified"/><label onClick={()=>this.getDocFinancialInfo(docId)}>Not Verified{docId}</label></td>;
  }else{
      docVerificationStatus[index] = <td className="green"><img src={verified} alt="Verified" /><label>Verified</label></td>;
  }
});
```

the `this` in the `onClick` handler refers to the function you pass as a parameter to the `forEach` method on the first line of the snippet above. You could avoid that by converting the 'old style' function into an arrow function:

```
finData.forEach((docFinInfo, index) => {
    // your code here.
});
```

Now `this` will refer to the outer scope, in your case the class `UploadDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `getDocFinancialInfo` method outside the render method. Since it's a method for your component class.

Comment: It is outside the render method. I have corrected the mistake.